# JavaScript: module pattern differences

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

What is the difference between

```
var module = (function(){
    return {} 
})()
```

and

```
(function(context){
    var module = {}
    context.module = module;
})(this)
```

Comment: If this is in global scope, they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Another one that I came up with a few months ago is `var module = new function() { /* use this as the module */ }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A property of `this` is not equivalent to a variable. In the global scope (i.e. where `this` references `window`), they are similiar. Yet, for example they will have a different behavior when you try to [`delete`](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) them:

```
> this.module = {};
> delete this.module
true
> var module = {};
// cant be deleted
```

Apart from that, both snippets create an empty object, wrapped inside a closure where you could define local (private) variables/functions etc. In your second function the object is also assigned to the local variable `module`, but that could be done in the first one as well.

---

@Eric: Your approach, using the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/new), is similiar to the first one regarding the variable. However, it will create an instance of that anonymous function instead of returning a plain object. It will inherit properties from a custom prototype, so for example `module.constructor` will then point to the anonymous function (which cannot be garbage collected, but e.g. even reused to create a clone). I would not recommend to use this.

Comment: +1 (I didn't not know `var` had that affect in the global scope; I thought it was simply "ignored". Is this for ECMAScript 3rd edition as well?)

Comment: Uh, that was on a comment by @Eric. I thought it would be the OP's one

Answer (score 0):

Top one is revealing module pattern. It lets you define private functions (as much as you can in javascript) and choose which ones are made public via the return call.

```
var module = (function(){ 
    function foo() {}; // Public, since it's returned

    function bar() {}; // Private, since it is not returned

    return {
        foo: foo
    } 
})();
```

The bottom one, as far as I can tell, just assigns an object literal to another object's namespace. It's probably the start of a singelton pattern.

```
(function(context){
    var module = {};
    context.module = module;
}(this)
```

The module could actually be defined with the revealing module pattern, hard to say since in your example it's just an object literal.

Comment: In the second one you also can have private stuff and choose which to expose then.

Comment: @MikeRobinson: Both patterns create singleton modules. There is no real difference in that aspect

Comment: This is not true. They are effectively the same in this aspect (of new scope and visibility patterns). The first simply assigns to `window.module` (a property assignment to `module` in the global scope) while the 2nd implicitly assigns to `window.module` through `context.module` through `this` (evaluates to `window` when called).

Comment: Which leads me to the next question. Also just wondering. Is there a pattern to create several instances of a module. Or what approach is suitable for that case?

Comment: @monkee Generally a "module" is a *singleton* with a "stable well-known name". Whereas objects from constructors/prototypes (or "classes") are instantiated one or more times .. of course, since a "module" *is* an object (with a "stable well-known name") ..

Comment: By the way, the revealing module pattern doesn't use anonymous functions

Comment: @pst thank you. Coming from as3, js is a lot of fun and confusing sometimes.