# abandoning javascript namespacing and revealing module pattern in favor of intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, design-patterns

after spending the past few days in frustration trying to refractor my code into the an optimal design pattern, namely the revealing module pattern, or even just settleing for simple namespacing, I have come to the conclusions that for me, the pros of an elegant design pattern are outweighed by the cons of destroying visual studio intellisense support.

I am therefore resorting to the following solution:

declare modules in the following manner:

```
var namespaceprefix_someModule = new function(){

  function privatemethod(){}

  this.publicmethod = function(){};

}
```

I willing to pay the price of having 5 global variables.
in return, the code can be neatly divided into functional modules on different files,
and with strong intellisense support.

I am wondering if anyone here proposes an alternate solution.

Comment: Hum, my alternate solution is that you don't do that and code the in the best way you can instead of favoring a tool that doesn't do anything you can't do by yourself. But that just me. You could try another editor?

Comment: I agree. which is why I was hesitant to go this route. the way I see it, choosing a design pattern is largely to ease code maintenance, and if I have to sacrefice intellisense for a pattern, it better have some big advantages because intellisense is a huge factor in easing code maintenance.  If you know of an IDE that has better intellisense for javascript please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really not use that pattern with the `new` operator, for [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132454/1048572). Instead, use

```
var namespaceprefix_someModule = (function(){

    function privatemethod(){}

    return {
        publicmethod: function(){}
    };
})();
```

I am not sure, but I think VS recognises this pattern.

Comment: Thank you. this worked. strange since I was sure I already tried this combination.  I was hpoing I could intellisense to work with  namespaceprefix.somemodule.

Answer (score 1):

What I have finally decided upon is to design the code so that an underscore can be easily replaced with a `.` (dot) when moving to production. This way I develop with full IntelliSense and end up with only one global variable at the end.

During development, a module looks like this:

```
namespace_module1 = (function(){

   function private(){};

   function public(){};

   return {
     public: public
   }

})();
```

The main module serves as a mediator role by linking events in one module with public functions of another module. It looks like:

```
var namespace = (function(){

   var module1 = namespace_module1;
   var module2 = namespace_module2;

   module1.on('someevent', module2.publicfunction);

})();
```