# JavaScript Module pattern, is new a good idea?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn the JavaScript module pattern referenced [here](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/). Everything looks great but I keep seeing different ways to create the module.

In the article referenced above he access the module's public methods by using `YAHOO.myProject.myModule.init();` without calling `new`.  But then I've seen a few people do something like `var module = new YAHOO.myProject.myModule();`.  Should `new` be used and why?

Comment: What does you module do? There are reasons to use `new`, but it happens seldom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no right or wrong answer to this.

Sometimes a module will contain an object, where no new keyword is needed.

```
define( [], function() {
   return {
      foo: "bar"
   };
};
```

Sometimes a module will contain a constructor for an object, where a new keyword is needed.

```
define( [], function() {
   return function() {
      this.foo = "bar";
   };
};
```

Sometimes a module will contain a function that returns new objects, where no new keyword is needed.

```
define( [], function() {
   var SomeConstructor = function() {
      this.foo = "bar";
   };
   return function() {
      return new SomeConstructor();
   };
};
```

Usage depends partially on what you are trying to accomplish and partially on your teams coding preference.

Answer (score 1):

That all comes down to exactly what is inside of `myModule`.

If the intent of `myModule` is to return a 100% new object, and inside of `myModule` there are a whole lot of assignments using `this.<X> = <Y>`, then yes, `new` would be the anticipated course of action.

...if it wasn't looking to create a new object, then `this` would refer to `myProject` and any `this.<X> = <Y>;` assignments would be reflected as `YAHOO.myProject.<X> = <Y>;` and using `new` would be a bad idea, if you were expecting then to use `YAHOO.myProject.<X>` to do something...

So it really all depends on what's going on.

A lot of JavaScript-fluent programmers (those who are used to thinking about JS differently than writing C++ or Java or C#) will try to avoid using patterns where `new` is required in cases like these, because it's ambiguous as to what `myModule` ***is*** and there are a lot of other suitable patterns which are dead-simple to implement in JS.

Answer (score 0):

As modules usually are singletons and not constructors, you should not use `new`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132454/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword in Javascript allocates a new object, and then sets it as `this` in the constructor invocation.  If you're simply using a module as a function that will return an object allocated in the function itself, `new` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Because, when declaring at least, javascript makes no distinction between objects and functions, new has to be used when you create the object. However, you'll often fine that patterns like this occur.

```
function myObject() {
    if (!(this instanceof myObject)) {
        return new myObject();
    }
}
```

This is done to make sure that it's always an instance of `myObject`.